# What are the FAA's requirements for an experimental type certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, experimental-aircraft

What is required by the FAA to obtain an experimental type certificate for a manned prototype aircraft?

Answer (score 4):

Found it. It's easy to get lost in the FAR's, but in case you're curious I managed to find the requirements I was looking for under [14 CFR 21.193](https://ecfr.io/Title-14/se14.1.21_1193):

> An applicant for an experimental certificate must submit the following
>   information:
>
> (a) A statement, in a form and manner prescribed by the FAA setting
>   forth the purpose for which the aircraft is to be used.
>
> (b) Enough data (such as photographs) to identify the aircraft.
>
> (c) Upon inspection of the aircraft, any pertinent information found
>   necessary by the FAA to safeguard the general public.
>
> (d) In the case of an aircraft to be used for experimental purposes—
>
> (1) The purpose of the experiment;
>
> (2) The estimated time or number of flights required for the
>   experiment;
>
> (3) The areas over which the experiment will be conducted; and
>
> (4) Except for aircraft converted from a previously certificated type
>   without appreciable change in the external configuration, three-view
>   drawings or three-view dimensioned photographs of the aircraft.
>
> (e) In the case of a light-sport aircraft assembled from a kit to be
>   certificated in accordance with §21.191(i)(2), an applicant must
>   provide the following:
>
> (1) Evidence that an aircraft of the same make and model was
>   manufactured and assembled by the aircraft kit manufacturer and issued
>   a special airworthiness certificate in the light-sport category.
>
> (2) The aircraft's operating instructions.
>
> (3) The aircraft's maintenance and inspection procedures.
>
> (4) The manufacturer's statement of compliance for the aircraft kit
>   used in the aircraft assembly that meets §21.190(c), except that
>   instead of meeting §21.190(c)(7), the statement must identify assembly
>   instructions for the aircraft that meet an applicable consensus
>   standard.
>
> (5) The aircraft's flight training supplement.
>
> (6) In addition to paragraphs (e)(1) through (e)(5) of this section,
>   for an aircraft kit manufactured outside of the United States,
>   evidence that the aircraft kit was manufactured in a country with
>   which the United States has a Bilateral Airworthiness Agreement
>   concerning airplanes or a Bilateral Aviation Safety Agreement with
>   associated Implementation Procedures for Airworthiness concerning
>   airplanes, or an equivalent airworthiness agreement.
>
> [Doc. No. 5085, 29 FR 14569, Oct. 24, 1964, as amended by Amdt. 21-85,
>   69 FR 44862, July 27, 2004]